# Remove items from list<a> AND list<b> when a.Foo == b.Bar

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm looking for an elegant way of comparing 2 different List<> collections and removing the items in which a specific field value matches.  For example:
Customer object

```
class Customer
{ 
    string CustomerName;
    string Email;
}

class Employee
{
    string EmployeeName;
    string EmployeeID;
 }

 List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customers(GetCustomers());
 List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employees(GetEmployees());
```

And then I know I can do this to remove from the Employees list the Employees that are in the Customers list by doing like this:

```
 Employees.RemoveAll(e => Customers.Any(c.CustomerName == e.EmployeeName));
```

What I would like to know is how I can also remove from the Customers list the corresponding Employee?  Is it possible to do with a simple statement or do I need to build something out to handle this?

Comment: i cant see it being done with 1 line of code, but perhaps using intersect it can be done with 3.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb910215(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about:

```
Employees.Where(e => Customers.Any(c=> c.CustomerName == e.EmployeeName)).ToList()
    .ForEach(e=> { 
         Employees.Remove(e); 
         Customers.RemoveAll(c => c.CustomerName == e.EmployeeName);
     });
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for.  I didn't realize that multiple steps could be implemented in a .ForEach (which is great since I do need to add an additional action). If that's the case then I'm guessing that even though the Employees.Remove(e) is done in the previous step, I still have the original e variable that I can use for Customers.RemoveAll(c => c.CustomerName == e.EmployeeName)? I will give this a try and see how it works.

Comment: @divamatrix yeah the remove only takes it out of the collection (ie it doesnt dispose the object)

Answer (score 0):

Create one list of all customers to be deleted and another of all employees to be deleted first. Then delete all these from your original lists. I am not firm enough with lambda to write this out from memory, but it should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

lets try:

```
List<Customer> c = new List<Customer>();
c.Add(new Customer() {CustomerName = "test", Email = "email" });
c.Add(new Customer() { CustomerName = "test1", Email = "email1" });
c.Add(new Customer() { CustomerName = "test2", Email = "email2" });
c.Add(new Customer() { CustomerName = "test3", Email = "email3" });
List<Employee> e = new List<Employee>();
e.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeName = "test2", EmployeeID = "1" });
e.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeName = "test1", EmployeeID = "2" });
e.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeName = "test5", EmployeeID = "3" });
e.Add(new Employee() { EmployeeName = "test4", EmployeeID = "4" });

//remove from the Customers list the corresponding Employee 
e.RemoveAll(x => c.Any(y => y.CustomerName == x.EmployeeName));

foreach (var employee in e)
{
    //TODO: 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inBoth = customers.Join(employees, customer => customer.CustomerName, employee => employee.EmployeeName, (customer, employee) => employee.EmployeeName).ToList();

customers.RemoveAll(customer => inBoth.Contains(customer.CustomerName));
employees.RemoveAll(employee => inBoth.Contains(employee.EmployeeName));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
var toBeDeleted = employees.Select(e => e.EmployeeName)
                           .Where(name => customers.Any(c => c.CustomerName == name))
                           .ToList();
customers.RemoveAll(c => toBeDeleted.Contains(c.CustomerName));
employees.RemoveAll(e => toBeDeleted.Contains(e.EmployeeName));
```

You might be able to use `Intersect` instead to get the elements that should be deleted. I am unaware of any one line command that can do this.